# mysql transaction vs lock

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have a question regarding MySQL locking and transaction management.
 My Question is ..does mysql takes lock on the the tuple/table on which I am doing select/update in a transaction ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With MyISAM, you can use the `concurrent_insert=2` optimization, where an `INSERT` will not block existing or new `SELECT` statements (but will block anything else).

With InnoDB, the rules are:

- `SELECT`s never block
- An `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on a row will place
  a lock on said row. But this can work even while the same row is
  being `SELECT`ed.
- A second update (on concurrent transaction) on
  same row will block, until the first is committed or rolled back.
- `INSERT`s are more complicated: if the table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then that is locked (though other concurrent operations are allowed if not competing for `AUTO_INCREMENT`)
- Some concurrent `INSERT`s may block one another because locking is done over the clustered index.
- `DELETE`s, `UPDATE`s on ranges are also more complex and may involve firther blocks due to locks on clustered index.

This is probably not a thorough list, but should get you the general picture.

Comment: Is it correct to say that single update or delete statement e.g. update table set column1 = x, outside of transaction is/acts like a micro transaction.

Comment: With InnoDB - yes; no UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, SELECT can operate outside a transaction. If not declared otherwise, they operate within their own singular transactions.

Answer (score 3):

## [**MYISAM**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Each INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE performs a full table lock before perform in the SQL command.

## [**InnoDB**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html)

MySQL's [**ACID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)-compliant storage engine, InnoDB performs row-level (tuple-level) locking. InnoDB performs [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) to support [transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_isolation). The level for Transaction Isolation in InnoDB are

- [READ-UNCOMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)
- [READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)
- [REPEATABLE-READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) (default)
- [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable)

There are other posts I have for to look over to see how InnoDB and MyISAM differ

- `Apr 14, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)
- `Sep 14, 2011` : [Benefits of table level locking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/benefits-of-table-level-locking/5782#5782)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Best of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/best-of-myisam-and-innodb/6008#6008)
- `Feb 28, 2012` : [read before write transaction](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11868/read-before-write-transaction/14058#14058)
- `May 02, 2012` : [Which mysql storage engine to choose?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17372/which-mysql-storage-engine-to-choose/17374#17374)
- `May 03, 2012` : [Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/which-is-faster-innodb-or-myisam/17434#17434)
- `May 16, 2012` : [Why doesn't InnoDB store the row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count/17992#17992)

Comment: Hi rolando..i have read your the wiki link in your post..